# Q. Infinity Java math equation and double length count

Tags: java, string-length, infinity

This is for infinite geometric progression. How would I go about having the following in infinity value? To have m start from 1 and go up by 1 each time in infinity and have valueTwo be the sum of all. This is in a while loop.

```
double valueTwo;
double m = 1;

valueTwo = Math.pow(0.5, m-1)/0.5;
```

Also how would I go about counting the length of the absolute? I have the following but it keeps giving me the error "double cannot be dereferenced."

If absolute is 9.765625E-4, how can I have it to show "0-th till 10-th".

```
String[] splitter = absolute.toString().split("\\.");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There were used terms from " + splitter[0].length() 
       + "-th till " + splitter[1].length() + "-th" + "\nin the geometric progression.");
```

Comment: Your first question is really unclear. For the second one, `double` is a primitive type so you cannot call a method on a `double` variable. Use the `Double` wrapper instead

Comment: There is no such thing as a data-type with infinite precision.

Comment: So I changed to Double absolute; and absolute = 2 - valueTwo; but it is saying "variable absolute might not have been initialized" and another variable using absolute is getting the same message.